# why can we use always_ff inside always_comb in SystemVerilog?

Tags: system-verilog

I'm trying to create flipflops to do the shift operations then a mux to select the proper behavior that I wanted. However, SystemVerilog does not allow me to switch from sequential logic(flipflops) to combinational. Do you have any recommendations? Thanks

```
/*
    Problem 3: Consider the following design Model_1:
    a) a 8-bit input data_in [7:0]
    b) 8 register outputs data_out [7:0]
    c) Clock(CLK)
    d) a 3-bit operation code OP [2:0].
    The function of the OP code is defined as:
    000: Reset all registers to 0
    001: Arithmetic shift right (shift right and keep the highest bit value)
    010: Arithmetic shift left (shift left and fill the lowest bit with 0)
    011: Shift right (shift right lowest bit wraps to the highest bit)
    100: Shift left (shift left the highest bit wraps to the lowest bit)
    101: Keep current registers’ data
    110: Default (You can define your own logic/arithmetic operations)
    Tasks:
    Write and simulate a synthesizable 8-bit shifter register model in Systemverilog .
    */

module Model_1(output logic [7:0] data_out,input logic [7:0] data_in,input CLK,input logic [2:0] OP);
localparam zero = 0'b0;
always_comb
unique casez(OP)
3'b000: data_out = 8'b00000000;//Reset all registers to 0
3'b001: //Arithmetic shift right (shift right and keep the highest bit value)
        always_ff @(posedge CLK) data_out <= {data_in[7], data_in[7:1]}; ;
3'b010:  //Arithmetic shift left (shift left and fill the lowest bit with 0)
        always_ff @(posedge CLK) data_out <= {data_in[6:0], zero}; ;
3'b011: //Shift right (shift right lowest bit wraps to the highest bit)
        always_ff @(posedge CLK) data_out <= {data_in[0], data_in[7:1]}; ;
3'b100: //Shift left (shift left the highest bit wraps to the lowest bit)
        always_ff @(posedge CLK) data_out <= {data_in[6:0], data_in[7]}; ;
3'b101: data_out = data_in;//Keep current registers’ data
default: data_out = 8'b????????;
endcase
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use nested always blocks because it is **not** a part of the language definition.

A verilog module consists of the `assign` statements,  procedural blocks (`always`, `initial`, `final`), and `instances` of other modules (or other design elements).

Procedural blocks can contain algorithmic code and event control statements, but they cannot contain any elements which belong to the module level.

To express hierarchy, you instantiate modules inside other modules.

In your case you can express your  logic in a single flop, something like the following:

```
always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
    unique casez(OP)
    3'b000: 
        data_out <= 8'b00000000;
    3'b001: 
        data_out <= {data_in[7], data_in[7:1]}; ;
    3'b010:  
        data_out <= {data_in[6:0], zero}; ;
    ...
    endcase
end
```

You need to go through verilog tutorials to master the language.

Comment: Thank you for your help! It is my first SystemVerilog/Verilog class that's why I'm having some troubles with the language.